# Can CSS code redundancy with multiple media queries be avoided?

Tags: css

I have a picture with a specific size:

```
.image-size {
    height: 400px
}
```

For smaller screens, I decrease this size:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .image-size {
        height: 280px
    }
}
```

But when the page is printed, I need the original size:

```
@media print {
    .image-size {
        height: 400px
    }
}
```

I tried to avoid the code redundancy with

```
@media print, (max-width: 50000px)
    .image-size {
        height: 400px
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .image-size {
        height: 280px
    }
}
```

but that did not work with small screens because the print size 400 was overwritten with the small screen size 280.

Is there a way to avoid the code redundancy?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the media `screen` for responsive rules:

```css
.image-size {
   height: 400px
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .image-size {
        height: 280px
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: NP, you can mark this answer as accepted.